# Querying distinct logins using LoginHistory and COUNT_DISTINCT

Tags: soql, aggregate, group-by

I seem to have run in to a SOQL error that I'm hoping someone has solved before.

I am creating a dashboard for UserLogins using the [LoginHistory object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_loginhistory.htm)

The query I am trying to run is:

```
SELECT COUNT_DISTINCT(userid) agg 
FROM loginhistory 
WHERE logintime = THIS_MONTH 
AND userid IN ('id1', 'id2', ...)
```

When I run the query I get back this agg result:

```
[ {
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "AggregateResult"
  },
  "agg" : 1
} ]
```

What I need is the number of distinct logins within the time frame, however when I add a GROUP BY UserID salesforce errors:

> "Grouped field should not be aggregated: UserId"

Query:

```
SELECT userid,COUNT_DISTINCT(userid) agg 
FROM loginhistory 
WHERE logintime = TODAY 
AND userid IN ('id1','id1') 
GROUP BY userid
```

Comment: IF you run: SELECT userid,COUNT_DISTINCT(userid) agg FROM loginhistory WHERE logintime = TODAY  you get "MALFORMED_QUERY: Field must be grouped or aggregated: UserId"

Comment: If you run: "SELECT userid,COUNT_DISTINCT(userid) agg FROM loginhistory WHERE logintime = TODAY GROUP BY UserId" you get MALFORMED_QUERY: 
SELECT userid,COUNT_DISTINCT(userid) agg FROM loginhistory WHERE
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:30
Grouped field should not be aggregated: UserId

Comment: Final comment: the reason I can't do a COUNT is each time you login you get a new LoginHistory record, we just are trying to identify if they did login during that time window

Comment: I do not have an answer for the query but one way of getting what you want is to query the LoginHistory table and add the returned userId values to a Set which will remove duplicates.

Comment: Thanks but in super large orgs you'll blow out the record collection size, my user has 40+ login history objects for today only, so across multiple thousand people you can't query them all back so you must use the aggregate results

Comment: May be I am not understanding your requirement correctly, but do you even need to use the count_distinct? if you execute the following query, you will get one record for each unique user that logged in today. `Select userid from LoginHistory where logintime = today group by userid`.

Comment: Userid is lookup field ?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Count(Id) agg, userId acc 
FROM LoginHistory 
GROUP BY UserId
```